# how i can sum an column in datatable in different dates?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i am trying to sum an column in datatable by different dates and displaying the value in textbox but only i am getting the first row value in the column not the the sum ,  i attached an picture and my code is

```
     Dim dt As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("
        SELECT
            SUM(PT.PT_Paid)   AS SumOfPT_Paid
          , SUM(PT.PT_Remain) AS SumOfPT_Remain
          , PT.PT_Date
        FROM
            PT
        GROUP BY
            PT.PT_Date
        HAVING
            (
                (
                    (
                        PT.PT_Date
                    )
                    >=#{0}#
                    AND
                    (
                        PT.PT_Date
                    )
                    <=#{1}#
                )
            )
        ;", dateshow.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), dateshow2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    txtin.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
    txtremain.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
Else
    txtin.Text = "0"
    txtremain.Text = "0"
End If
```

Data:

[image]

Comment: Plz add data as code not image!

Comment: Dim dt As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("SELECT Sum(PT.PT_Paid) AS SumOfPT_Paid, Sum(PT.PT_Remain) AS SumOfPT_Remain, PT.PT_Date FROM PT GROUP BY PT.PT_Date HAVING (((PT.PT_Date)>=#{0}# And (PT.PT_Date)<=#{1}#));", dateshow.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), dateshow2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            txtin.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
            txtremain.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
        Else
            txtin.Text = "0"
            txtremain.Text = "0"
        End If

Comment: And don't add code as comment. Wait until my edits are reviewed and please don't destroy my formatting as it makes your code readable.

Comment: Your date format seems wrong, try `mm/dd/yyyy` or ``yyyy/mm/dd` .and show  the table data.of PT.